# Disable HipChat notifications per room

Tags: notifications, hipchat

I have used HipChat for over a year, but with few demands on it. Lately, my team has started to use the HipChatAPI to publish changes from GitHub to a new chat room. I like this, but would like to not be notified (flashing taskbar, pop-ups, etc.) when this particular room updates. I would still like to see standard notifications on the other rooms.

I scoured both the AIR client and the WebApp options, but didn't see this level of notification granularity. I only found options to disable taskbar/sound/pop-up notifications for ALL rooms.

Does anyone know how to suppress notifications for a particular room?

Comment: There's a topic suggesting this idea here: http://help.hipchat.com/forums/138883-suggestions/suggestions/2800009-more-granular-and-per-room-notification-alert-sett Many people are wanting this, but no word yet if they are planning on implementing it or not.

Answer (score 1):

When you make the API call, there is a *notify* option that triggers the notification, which is off by default, so it looks like someone turned it on intentionally.

[Source](https://www.hipchat.com/docs/api/method/rooms/message).

Answer (score 1):

Being on the *room*, click on *Room notification* (alarm icon in the top-right corner) where you can customize notification for the channel. From there select the *Quiet* mode.

[image: HipChat - Room notifications]